# Help determining probability of multiple, related, coin flips

Tags: probability

This question is missing a piece of info, it's been re asked

I'm trying to figure out if my school can get a bowl game, but for simplicities sake, I'm going to use a coin flip analogy.

You have a coin flipped 19 times, head means win, tails means loss. You have 17 free spaces to fill. Each time the coin is heads, you fill in one of the spaces. If there are spaces left, continue to the next step.

You have a list with 13 items. Flip the coin 12 times, once for each item on the list, going in order (we're going to assume that the 13th item will always be heads). If the coin is heads, put that item into one of the spaces mentioned earlier. My question is, what is the probability that the 13th item will have a space to fit into?

Example:
Flip set 1: 10 heads, 9 tails. 7 free spaces remain
Flip set 2: 6 heads, 6 tails. 1 free space remains. 13th item fits.

Example 2:
Flip set 1: 12 heads, 7 tails. 5 free spaces remain.
Flip set 2: 7 heads, 5 tails. No free spaces remain. 13th item does not fit.

Comment: You are basically asking what is the probability of getting less than or equal to 16 heads in 31 coin flips.

Comment: Your school can get to a bowl game if it wins 6 games, but no one than one game that is a win can be versus a school lower than FBS level if the end win total is only 6 wins

Comment: Actually, a 5-7 team can get to a bowl, but that's based on the APR. That's what I'm trying to determine. There's a chart of the current APR of all potential 5-7 teams, so using that I'm trying to figure out what the probability is. It ends up being around .696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a total of 31 coin flips, and are trying to determine if between them they use up all the 17 slots. So the question is: "what is the probability that there are $\leq 16$ heads out of 31 coin flips?"

There are $\sum_{i=0}^{16}\binom{31}{i}=1,374,282,019$ ways of flipping 31 coins with less than or equal to 16 heads. There are $2^{31}=2,147,483,648$ ways of flipping 31 coins altogether.

Thus, the probability of there being a space left over is 0.64.

Comment: Thanks, I actually left out a crucial part of info that makes this problem more complicated. I'm going to re ask it